# Document without title

Tags: formatting

Sometimes I want to create a page of text without extra structure; no title, pagination, or other frills. What is the proper way to achieve this? For lack of a "correct" way, I just open a document class and leave empty title etc, then use `\thispagestyle{empty}`, and then play with raising the text to fill the title space. This ought to be the wrong way to go about it, but I have not found a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `\pagestyle{empty}` and type the text.

```
% pageprob.tex  SE 560441
\documentclass{book}
%\documentclass{report}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

All three classes just typeset the text with no page numbers or header/footer.

Answer (score 1):

No title, no pagination, no sections, no document class, no list with bullets, or numbers,  or spaces among items, no everything. Just raw text:

```
\def\normalsize{\normalfont}
\RequirePackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\textwidth16cm\textheight20cm
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-80]  % dummy text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

OP stated in one comment, that my answer/solution leaves

> a lot of empty space where the title should have been

While I cannot reproduce this behavior with the code I've provided, a little bit of thinking has brought me to the conclusion that if one were after the most economical use of space on the page, `KOMA-Script` offers a simple (yet typographically undesirable) way to achieve it:

```
\documentclass[DIV=16]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{empty}
% \pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: KOMA empty page]

I am not entirely sure, there is a »correct way« to typeset an empty page. I think, the closest you can get is by leaving out most of the usual information (such as title, author, date etc.). This will get rid of most of the things you don't want. With `\pagenumbering{gobble}` you can suppress the pagenumbers and you should be good to go:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{empty}
% \pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

## Behold, a no frills, no title, no author, no pagination document!

[image: minimal example]

Comment: Do you mean `\pagestyle{empty}`, perhaps?

Comment: Doen't this solution leave a lot of empty space where the title should have been? My peeve is having to compensate for that. Sometimes I skip a page, and then crop the PDF; clearly not optimal...

Comment: @egreg, thank you for the hint, I will edit my answer.